# Expressing similarity in different aspects

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Is it right to express similarity like this?

> My brother and I look [alike] / [like each other] not only **in** appearance, but also **in** behaviors.

Is there a better way to express it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the word **similar**, as it has a broader meaning than look alike.

> My brother and I are quite similar, not only in appearance, but also in behavior.

Comment: Thanks. So, you mean using "in" is proper, don't you?

Comment: How about using *behavior* as a mass noun?  "…, but also in **behavior**."

Comment: @mok: yup, **in** is fine.